# How to get last row which matches values in 2 columns on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a transaction table that contains the transaction of items bought whenever they are bought. Latest transaction will contains the total amount spent on that item after the item is bought.

I want to create a chart table of the amount spent over time based (daily) on the item. I use the following formula to get the row number of the item's latest transaction

`ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(Transaction!$B:$B="Apple",ROW(Transaction!$B:$B),-1))) --> returns 6`'

But I can't seem to add on to this formula to get the latest row based on Item and if the Date is less than or equals to my chart date

**TRANSACTION TABLE**

| 1 | Date | Item | Amount | Prev. Spent | Curr. Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 Jan 2020 | Apple | $10 | $0 | $10 |
| 3 | 1 Jan 2020 | Banana | $12 | $0 | $12 |
| 4 | 2 Jan 2020 | Corn | $3 | $0 | $3 |
| 5 | 2 Jan 2020 | Banana | $5 | $12 | $17 |
| 6 | 3 Jan 2020 | Apple | $50 | $10 | $60 |
| 7 | 5 Jan 2020 | Banana | $23 | $17 | $40 |

**CHART TABLE**

| Date | Apple | Banana | Corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan 2020 | $10 | $12 | $0 |
| 2 Jan 2020 | $10 | $17 | $3 |
| 3 Jan 2020 | $60 | $17 | $3 |
| 4 Jan 2020 | $60 | $17 | $3 |
| 5 Jan 2020 | $60 | $40 | $3 |

Comment: Are you open to using an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: yea i dont mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem with simple formula, I would use `sumifs` function:

```
=sumifs($D:$D,$C:$C,I$15,$B:$B,$H17)+I16
```

Here is how the Gsheet data look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of this! This works perfectly

Comment: Welcome, as long as you find it simple to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this via a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script. To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project (check inline comments for more information about what the function is doing):

```
function getTable(values) {
  let times = values.map(row => row[0].getTime());
  const minTime = Math.min(...times); // Get first day in series
  const maxTime = Math.max(...times); // Get last day in series
  times = getTimes(minTime, maxTime); // Get all days between minimum and maximum
  const items = [...new Set(values.map(row => row[1]))]; // Get unique list of items
  let targetValues = [["Date", ...items]]; // Header row
  for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) { // Loop through all days
    const time = times[i];
    const dayRows = values.filter(row => row[0].getTime() === time); // Get rows with this day
    if (dayRows) {
      const rowValues = items.map((item, j) => { // Loop through all items in day rows
        const foundRow = dayRows.find(row => row[1] === item); // Find row corresponding to day and item
        const previous = i === 0 ? 0 : targetValues[targetValues.length - 1][j + 1]; // Value in previous row
        if (foundRow) return foundRow[2] + previous;
        else return 0 + previous;
      });
      targetValues.push([new Date(time), ...rowValues]);
    } else { // If day is not in source data, values are the same than previous row
      targetValues.push([new Date(time), ...targetValues[targetValues.length - 1].slice(1)]);
    }
  }
  return targetValues;
}

function getTimes(minTime, maxTime) {
  let allTimes = [minTime];
  let currentTime = minTime;
  while (currentTime < maxTime) {
    let date = new Date(currentTime);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    currentTime = date.getTime();
    allTimes.push(currentTime);
  }
  return allTimes;
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use the function `getTable` as if you were using a regular sheets formula. You just have to provide the appropriate range as an argument (in this case `A2:E7`), as you can see here:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a formula in two stages.

1. `Transactions` tab:

[image]

2. `Pivot` tab, cell `A1`:

`=query({Transactions!A:F},"select Col2,max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3",1)`

[image]

3. `ChartData` tab, cell `A1`:

> ```
> =arrayformula(
>  array_constrain(
>   {Pivot!A1:D1;
>    (sequence(max(row(Pivot!A:A))-1,1,min(Transactions!$B:$B))),
>    sumif(row(Pivot!B2:B),"<="&row(Pivot!B2:B),Pivot!B2:B),
>    sumif(row(Pivot!C2:C),"<="&row(Pivot!C2:C),Pivot!C2:C),
>    sumif(row(Pivot!D2:D),"<="&row(Pivot!D2:D),Pivot!D2:D)
>   },
>  counta(Pivot!A:A)+1,counta(Pivot!1:1)))
> ```

[image]